# Bookshelf.js virtual field

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I'm creating a rest service with knex and bookshelf. I want to return all the record with a user specific field which is not in the database.

A good example would be a IsFavorite boolean field on a Book list request. I would then show something else to the user for a favorite book.

Now let's say I have 3 tables: User, Book and Favorite. How would I code the "get" IsFavorite field from the book record?

I saw that bookshelf support virtuals by doing something like this :

```
var User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  outputVirtuals: true,
  virtuals: {
    fullName: function() {
      return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }
  },
});
```

but I can't figure out how to fetch from my Favorite table within the virtuals.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [one-to-one](http://bookshelfjs.org/#one-to-one) relationships

Comment: @ExplosionPills The one to one relationships would not work in my case because I need to know if the book is in the favorite of the current user requesting the list. The values change depending of the user.